# Error while installing Apache; error is "E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)"

Tags: ubuntu, apt, apache-httpd, dpkg

I followed an online article *to remove my Apache*  from my system.
I removed Apache through these commands

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2 apache2-utils
sudo rm -rf /etc/apache2-bin
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then in the article they mentioned to remove the files and directories of the results of `whereis apache2`.

After running the command `whereis apache2` I found

```
/usr/sbin/apache2/usr/share/apache2
/usr/lib/apache2
/usr/share/man/man8/apache2.8.gz
/etc/apache2
```

I removed the above directories and files through command `sudo rm -rf file_or_directory_name`.

Then I tried

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

I clicked **'y'** when the system asked `do you want to continue?`.

Then the error came:

```
Setting up apache2 (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.4) ...
cp: cannot stat ‘/usr/share/apache2/default-site/index.html’: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package apache2 (--configure): subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:  apache2 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried `sudo apt-get install apache2` again after running the `sudo apt-get update` command, but still got the same error results.

Comment: you can use `apt-file` to search for which package contains which file like so: `apt-file search /usr/share/apache2/default-site/index.html`. http://www.faqforge.com/linux/how-to-use-apt-file-to-find-which-deb-package-contains-a-specific-file/

Comment: Don't follow online tutorials blindly. *Do not* remove system files using `rm -rf`. That is what the packaging system is for.

Comment: yes , i realized that ,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To recover `/usr/share/apache2/default-site/index.html` you need to re-install `apache2-data`. Given your current situation, try

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2-data
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Presumably your system ended up in that state because `apt-get autoremove` didn't uninstall `apache2-data`, but your `rm -rf` removed the files it contained. Then `apt-get install apache2` would reckon that `apache2-data` was still installed and didn't need to be re-installed, but its files were gone...

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2 apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2-common

sudo apt-get --purge remove apache2

sudo apt-get autoremove --purge

sudo apt-get purge apache2-data
```

install

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Note, however, that it is not quite obvious how your answer is to be applied to solve the OPs problem; you may want to edit it to provide more explanation. Also, it would seem that essentially the steps you propose are the same as in @StephenKitt's answer; perhaps you could explain how your approach is different.